# Apply 2 filters to a collection, but only use 1 (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

My title was probably pretty vague. The scenario is that I have a collection of objects being displayed with an ng-repeat:

```
 Search : <input ng-model="searchText" /><button ng-click="Export(filteredEntry)">Export Data</button>
 <tbody id="itemTable">
 <tr ng-repeat="entry in (filteredEntries = (entries limitTo:pageSize | filter: searchText))" 
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

The amount of items shown is limited by "limitTo" with a button that lets you see the next or previous set in the collection, and is filtered by a search box. When a button is clicked, only the filtered results (filteredEntries) are passed to another table.

Lets say my collection is of 100 objects, and limitTo = 10. Let's also say that a user enters "Hat" into the search box, and the collection of 100 entries is now filtered down to 23 entries. **My problem** is that when I click on the Export button, only the first 10 items are passed (since limitTo and search are both being applied to filteredEntries). Is there a way I can limit the observed entries to 10 but pass all of the 23 entries to the export table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` to display only the top N items.  But your filter search will still search the whole array.  Here's a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qAiQOOLSwsPcz7tmSrF6?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="book in books | filter:searchText" ng-if="$index < 5">
```